# Probability Function of Donor State

Tags: semiconductor-physics, fermions

I am referring to the book 'Semiconductor Physics and Devices' by Donald A. Neaman.

Chapter 4.4.1 says that
"Each donor level has two possible spin orientations for the donor electron; thus each donor level has two quantum states. The insertion of an electron into one quantum state, however, precludes putting an electron into the second quantum state. The distribution function of donor electrons in the donor energy states is then slightly different than the Fermi-Dirac function."

The Fermi-Dirac function is than modified with a factor of 1/2 infront of the exponential.

Can someone explain to me why the 2nd electron cannot be placed in the same energy state but with an opposite spin orientation?

Comment: The state only has room for one, but doesn’t care about the spin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that the author has in mind the Coulomb interaction between the electrons. When the level is empty, an electron of either spin can be added to it. However, once the level is occupied by an electron, adding the second electron costs a Coulomb energy, $U$. Since the electrons are interacting, one strictly speaking, cannot describe the using Fermi-Dirac statistics - adding factor 1/2 is an ad-hoc way to remedy this problem, which works in this particular situation.